# innerHTML not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure why, but in this script, I am testing regular expressions and what the regexp object and methods return for learning purposes.
why is it not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/alexdiazthatsme/xUjuT/1/

```
var source = document.getElementById('sourcetext');
var string = string.innerHTML;
var regex  = /[a-n]/ig;
var found  = string.match(regex);

document.write(found[0]);
```

Comment: I think you did a string.innerHtml but meant source.innerHtml

Comment: `string.innerHTML` should be `source.innerHTML`. Also, use `/[a-n]/gi.exec(string);` instead of `string.match(/[a-n]/gi);`.

Comment: meta: _LOL, repofarmers' party_ :]

Answer (score 0):

Your original code :

```
var source = document.getElementById('sourcetext');
var string = string.innerHTML;
var regex  = /[a-n]/ig;
var found  = string.match(regex);

document.write(found[0]);
```

Maybe :

```
var source = document.getElementById('sourcetext');
var string = source.innerHTML;
var regex  = /[a-n]/ig;
var found  = string.match(regex);

document.write(found[0]);
```

On the 2nd line you are stating that the string (var you are currently creating) and then getting it's inner HTML - which, since you are creating it is still empty.

Probably a typos.

Comment: var source = document.getElementById('sourcetext');
  var str = source.innerHTML;
  var regex  = /[a-n]/ig;
  var found  = /[a-n]/gi.exec(str);
    
   document.write(found);
  I changed it, and still  , Firebug says : source is null

Comment: The code that I have suggested worked for me on the test site you had.  Copy paste and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have (one?) typo in your code, here's how it should look (?):
http://jsfiddle.net/kT8kM/

Comment: A typographical error (often shortened to [typo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error)) is a mistake made in .. the typing process.

Comment: what if you want to highlight all the matches? do you have to create a new paragraph and add a class to every matched string?

Comment: yes. There is no other way to implement this. _Well, you can wrap them in spans with inline style or `font` tags, but that's even more ugly_ ;)